# Applying Newey-West variance estimator without a regression framework

Tags: variance, neweywest

Let's say I have a series of correlated variables $x_1, ..., x_T$. I could estimate its variance by $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{i=1}^T (x_i - \bar{x})^2$. However, as there is serial correlation in the variable, I want a variance estimator that is robust to this. The Newey-West variance estimator has this property, but is usually applied in a regression framework.

Can someone provide me the formula of the Newey-West variance estimator in my setting?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, is it the variance of the data that you care about, or the variance of the _mean_ of the data?

Comment: In fact, I'm interested in both.